# Scrapy - Javascript rendering

Tags: scrapy

I would like to get some data from here:

https://www.drivy.com/location-voiture/liege/mitsubishi-colt-359699?address=Gare+de+Li%C3%A8ge-Guillemins&city_display_name=&country_scope=BE&distance=200&end_date=2019-05-27&end_time=06%3A00&latitude=50.6251&longitude=5.5659&start_date=2019-05-26&start_time=06%3A00

I'm searching for the ID of the owner of the car. This ID is within the `a`attribute of class `car_owner_section`. For the page above it is the numbers in the `href`attribute like this "/users/1228276". The issue is that this link is apparently rendered by javascript and I absolutely want to avoid scrapy-splash. Does anyone has an idea on how to find this ID ? It should be somewhere on a JSON I guess but I've searched for days now and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on scrapy shell, and the response returns the link you are looking for, without using splash. You might want to check your settings.

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```